# Recursive Tab Complete Filenames on :edit in VIM

Tags: vim, macvim

I had found a .vimrc configuration that allowed me to simply type

```
:e <<characters_in_filename>>
```

and then `tab` and the path would expand out to `:e full_path` or show me a list of options if there are similarly named files in my current path.

Anyone know how to make this happen?

note: I'm aware of FuzzyFileFinder, Peepopen, and CommandT, this has just really been bothering me.

It's very similar to the functionality described in this [google groups thread](http://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=bsp&ver=ohhl4rw8mbn4)

Comment: I had implemented zsh-like completion in vimcompcrtr plugin and it is used to create completion function for `e` (in `SE` command) by vimstuff (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3186) plugin. But the vim itself does not have same features: it will complete your file name only if you correctly wrote first characters. So, if you want good completion in the current directory then use CommandT. If you want good completion in the whole tree (though completion in the current directory is better in CommandT), wait until I move `SE` command to other plugin.

Comment: You can also play with `wildmenu` and `wildmode` options.

Answer (score 3):

As ZyX said, it sounds like you want `find`.

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=longest:full
set path+=./**
```

If you type `:find so<Tab>`, it will complete with all files that start with `so` searching recursively from the current file's directory (*not* pwd). (`<Tab>` can be changed with `wildchar`.)

You may prefer this kind of completion:

```
set wildmode=list:longest
```

And you could add your often used roots to `path` if you don't want recursive from the current file's directory.

```
set path+=~/code/**
```

---

If you just want to recurse from the current directory, try the above wild settings and use:

```
:edit **/so<Tab>
```

For more on specifying filenames see `:help {file}` and for more on `**`, see `:help starstar-wildcard`.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that `wildmenu` is on and try `:find` command.